# How to call function in GCP Instance from Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have created an instance on GCP to run some machine learning model for an app I am working on for a little project. I want to be able to call one of the methods in one of the files from my app and I thought a Cloud Function would be suitable.

To make this question simpler, let's just imagine I have a file in my instance called `hello.py` and a method in this file called `foo(sentence)`. And `foo(sentence)` simply returns the `sentence` parameter.

So how do I call this method `foo` in `python.py` and capture the output?

Thanks

Comment: Try to not simplify! I'm lost. Do you want to call a method inside a Cloud Functions? That's the deal? Pseudo code could be easier than a simplification ;-)

Comment: You'll probably want to make an HTTP request as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http). How you make that call will depend on what you're running in the VM.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere My mobile app is programmed in React Native (JS), I want to call a method there that then calls a Cloud Function, and this cloud function then calls a method in one of my instance files.

Comment: What's your "instance file"? A file in Cloud Functions? Or on your React Native app on your mobile?

Comment: My instance file is in my GCP Instance @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere so i created a VM on GCP and created an instance, and here I wrote the code for my model, ran it (to train the model), and there is a second file in the VM instance that calls a method in the model

Answer (score 2):

At Google Cloud (And Google also), "all is API". Thus, if you need to access from a product to another one, you need to do this through API calls.

If your Cloud Functions needs to invoke a script hosted on a Compute Engine VM instance, you need to expose an API on this Compute Engine instance. A simple flask server is enough, and expose it only on the private IP is also enough. But you can't directly access from your Cloud Functions code to the Compute Engine instance code.

You can also deploy a Cloud Functions (or a Cloud Run if you need more system packages/libraries) with the model loaded in it, and like this perform all the computation on the same product.

Comment: Thanks, I have heard of this Flask thing, I will take a look.